# right align input in table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a text input to the right of a table td but with no results. Here's what i have:

```css
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" /></td>
    <td class="right"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Mensagem" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input type="submit" id="sendform" value="Enviar">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by align right?  What do you want to see?

Comment: Why are you even using a table?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone im just used to do it like this.

Comment: `<table width:100%;>` isn't valid HTML. You probably meant `<table style="width:100%;">` in which case the cell that the email input is in will move to the right

Comment: Is it the _placeholder text_ that you want to be on the right side of the input control?  It is still not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @j08691 its a typo. thats what i meant. i'll try it out.

Comment: i wnat to make the input to be align to the right of the table. i'll edit the question.

Comment: ok... now it works here but not on my pc. =X

Answer (score 0):

The second `<input>` **is right aligned** inside the `<td>`.
But the `<input>` also happens to be just as wide as the `<td>`.

Run this to see what happens after forcing the `<td>` a bit wider, and the `<input>` a bit narrower. (I also added borders to make the effect more visible)

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 60px;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" /></td>
    <td class="right"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Mensagem" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input type="submit" id="sendform" value="Enviar">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tks for your answer. Here my code works but no on my pc. dont know what im doing wrong. maybe is bootstrap?